# Using JavaScript libraries in typescript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I am trying to use the [Phaser Input JS library](https://github.com/orange-games/phaser-input) in my TypeScript file.

I downloaded all the files to my project:

[image: folder]

I have referenced the js files in my HTML page,

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser-input.js"></script>
```

and in my app.ts file.

```
/// <reference path="phaser-input.d.ts" />
```

But when I try to use it in my ts file and I write

```
var input = game.add.inputField(10, 90);
```

I get the error

> Property 'inputField' does not exit on type 'GameObjectFactory'

Any suggestion on how to make it work is appreciated.

Comment: Is this error a compiler one or a runtime one?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is [Declaration Merging.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

The `phaser-input.d.ts` has it's own namespace `Fabrique`, and doesn't seem to merge to `Phaser` namespace or the `GameObjectFactory` class. So you need to do it manually by making another d.ts file and reference it in your app.ts

```
//index.d.ts
/// <reference path="phaser.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="phaser-input.d.ts" />

declare module Phaser {
  interface GameObjectFactory {
    inputField(x: number, y: number, inputOptions?: Fabrique.InputOptions): Fabrique.InputField
  }
}

//app.ts
///<reference path="index.d.ts" />

var input = game.add.inputField(10, 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax :

```
//phaser-input.d.ts
declare module "lib/phaser-input" {
  var input = game.add.inputField(10, 90);
}
```

Comment: Not for now, I'll tell you if I find something.